# Overlaying whiskers or error-bar-esque lines on a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lines, geom-bar, errorbar

I am creating plots similar to the first example image below, and need plots like the second example below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# some data
data.2015 = data.frame(score = c(-50,20,15,-40,-10,60),
                       area = c("first","second","third","first","second","third"),
                       group = c("Findings","Findings","Findings","Benchmark","Benchmark","Benchmark"))

data.2014 = data.frame(score = c(-30,40,-15),
                       area = c("first","second","third"),
                       group = c("Findings","Findings","Findings"))

# breaks and limits
breaks.major = c(-60,-40,-22.5,-10, 0,10, 22.5, 40, 60)
breaks.minor = c(-50,-30,-15,-5,0, 5, 15,30,50) 
limits =c(-70,70)

# plot 2015 data
ggplot(data.2015, aes(x = area, y = score, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limit = limits, oob = squish, minor_breaks = breaks.minor, breaks = breaks.major)
```

[image: sample plot]

The data.2014 has only values for the "Findings" group. I would like to show those 2014 Findings values on the plot, on the appropriate/corresponding data.2015$area, where there is 2014 data available.

To show last year's data just on the "Finding" (red bars) data, I'd like to use a one-sided errorbar/whisker that emanates from the value of the relevant data.2015 bar, and terminates at the data.2014 value, for example:

[image: ideal plot]

I thought to do this by using layers and plotting error bars so that the 2015 data could overlap, however this doesn't work when the 2014 result is abs() smaller than the 2015 result and is thus occluded.

Considerations:

- I'd like the errorbar/whisker to be the same width as the bars, perhaps even dashed line with a solid cap.
- Bonus points for a red line when the value has decreased, and green when the value has increased
- I generate lots of these plots in a loop, sometimes with many groups, with a different amount of areas in each plot. The 2014 data is (at this stage) always displayed only for a single group, and every area has some data (except for just one NA case, but need to provision for that scenario)

### EDIT

So I've added to the below solution, I used that exact code but instead used the `geom_linerange` so that it would add lines without the caps, then I also used the `geom_errorbar`, but with ymin and ymax set to the same value, so that the result is a one-sided error bar in `ggplot` `geom_bar`! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please check that the plots correspond to your data, i.e. group: Findings and Benchmark in data, vs group1, group2 in plot.

Comment: Why don't you post your full final code/plot as an additional answer for future readers?  I was thinking that separate cap/line would have to be something like that , good job figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get most of what you want with a little data manipulation.  Doing an outer join of the two datasets will let you add the error bars with the appropriate dodging.

```
alldat = merge(data.2015, data.2014, all = TRUE, by = c("area", "group"), 
            suffixes = c(".2015", ".2014"))
```

To make the error bar one-sided, you'll want `ymin` to be either the same as `y` or `NA` depending on the group.  It seemed easiest to make a new variable, which I called `plotscore`, to achieve this.

```
alldat$plotscore = with(alldat, ifelse(is.na(score.2014), NA, score.2015))
```

The last thing I did is to make a variable `direction` for when the 2015 score decreased vs increased compared to 2014.  I included a third category for the `Benchmark` group as filler because I ran into some issues with the dodging without it.

```
alldat$direction = with(alldat, ifelse(score.2015 < score.2014, "dec", "inc"))
alldat$direction[is.na(alldat$score.2014)] = "absent"
```

The dataset used for plotting would look like this:

```
    area     group score.2015 score.2014 plotscore direction
1  first Benchmark        -40         NA        NA    absent
2  first  Findings        -50        -30       -50       dec
3 second Benchmark        -10         NA        NA    absent
4 second  Findings         20         40        20       dec
5  third Benchmark         60         NA        NA    absent
6  third  Findings         15        -15        15       inc
```

The final code I used looked like this:

```
ggplot(alldat, aes(x = area, y = score.2015, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotscore, ymax = score.2014, color = direction), 
                position = position_dodge(width = .9), lwd = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(limit = limits, oob = squish, minor_breaks = breaks.minor, breaks = breaks.major) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "red", "green"))
```

[image]

I'm using the development version of *ggplot2*, ggplot2_1.0.1.9002, and `show_guide` is now deprecated in favor of `show.legend`, which I used in `geom_errorbar`.

I obviously didn't change the line type of the error bars to dashed with a solid cap, nor did I remove the bottom whisker as I don't know an easy way to do either of these things.

Comment: First, thanks for your effort, I know how long these posts can take. Great solution! I'm still new to R and the with() function looks like it will be in high rotation in my future code. I will open a new question about editing the error bars (weight, caps, line type etc) and add it here. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 0):

In response to a comment suggesting I add the full solution as an answer:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)

    # some data
    data.2015 = data.frame(score = c(-50,20,15,-40,-10,60),
                           area = c("first","second","third","first","second","third"),
                           group = c("Findings","Findings","Findings","Benchmark","Benchmark","Benchmark"))

    data.2014 = data.frame(score = c(-30,40,-15),
                           area = c("first","second","third"),
                           group = c("Findings","Findings","Findings"))

    # breaks and limits
    breaks.major = c(-60,-40,-22.5,-10, 0,10, 22.5, 40, 60)
    breaks.minor = c(-50,-30,-15,-5,0, 5, 15,30,50) 
    limits =c(-70,70)

    # reconfigure data to create values for the additional errorbar/linerange
    alldat = merge(data.2015, data.2014, all = TRUE, by = c("area", "group"), 
                suffixes = c(".2015", ".2014"))
    alldat$plotscore = with(alldat, ifelse(is.na(score.2014), NA, score.2015))
    alldat$direction = with(alldat, ifelse(score.2015 < score.2014, "dec", "inc"))
    alldat$direction[is.na(alldat$score.2014)] = "absent"

    ggplot(alldat, aes(x = area, y = score.2015, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +

    # set the data min and max as the same to have a single 'cap' with no line
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = score.2014, ymax = score.2014, color = direction), 
                    position = position_dodge(width = .9), lwd = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
    #then add the line
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin = score.2015, ymax = score.2014, color = direction), 
                    position = position_dodge(width = .9), lwd = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(limit = limits, oob = squish, minor_breaks = breaks.minor, breaks = breaks.major) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "red", "green"))
```